# woocommerce shortcode not on shop page

Tags: woocommerce, shortcode

I am the volunteer webmaster for a high school boosters club.
I have only about `10 products - 4 memberships` and `a number of "donate buttons"`.

On my shop page I have my memberships showing fine.  The donate buttons are `hidden from the shop page` using the `Catalog visibility option set to "search"`.

I want a page that just lists all of the donation buttons and I would think that the short code `[product_category category="donations"]` would do that even with the catalog visibility set to search.

**Question:** Is there any way to make that work?

Comment: I found a way to make this work but changing my "store" page to a different page.  I then created two new pages "memberships" and "donations" and put the short code on each page to display the products I want to show.  The store page isn't visible on the menu, so this works well for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to make this work but changing my "store" page to a different page. I then created two new pages "memberships" and "donations" and put the short code on each page to display the products I want to show. The store page isn't visible on the menu, so this works well for me